# How to use Git on Synology from Android Studio?

Tags: android, git, android-studio, synology

I installed Git server on NAS Synology and setup it as it is decribed [here](http://shaching.github.io/2014/07/16/git-how-to-install-git-server-in-synology-ds214-nas/).

I connected with Putty to NAS and do following on Git:

```
$ cd /volume1/Repository/

$ mkdir moonlightbox.git

$ cd moonlightbox.git

$ git --bare init

$ cd ..

$ chown -R git:users moonlightbox.git

$ exit
```

After that I followed [this](http://wii.logdown.com/posts/2013/11/15/android-studio-git-tutorial) manual to setup Git in Android Studio.

- I installed Git for Windows and setup path in Android Studio - Settings
- I enabled VCS for Git

But how I can connect current project in Android Studio with prepared empty repository created on NAS?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I have reached pretty much the same point and have not been able to find any information on getting any further.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you cannot connect a local repository within android studio. You have to use directly git (e.g. from the git bash)

```
 git remote add --track master origin ssh://user@server/volume1/Repository/moonlightbox.git

 # you need to specify the remote and branch the first time, not sure why
 # you also need to have some commits to push
 git push origin master
```

You can then use the `Push` ou `Pull` dialogs from the `VCS`/`Git` menu